# Is there any way to mark a modified folder in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I am using VS2012 with TFS (Team Foundation Server) as the source control tool and it works very well.
However, I found that when I modify a file under its folder, only the file was marked as "changed" status(with a red check-mark icon), but the folder not.

I've used VisualSVN Client(a VS2012 plugin), and it provides the feature above. It's really convenient to find the modified files when your project has a lot of folders.

Is there any method to achieve the similar feature in TFS? Or any VS extension can do that?

Comment: You can see all the pending changes via Pending Changes window of Visual Studio (under View menu->Other Windows). Will it help meet you needs?

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's just the answer I wanted. I had thought that the Pending Changes window will not be displayed until you check in the code. It seems i still a little less adaptation to TFS. Thanks again.